# Adding a NOT VALID foreign key in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl

Example schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3d410

I've already got a table and I want to add a new, not valid foreign key to the table.  What's the correct syntax for adding a NOT VALID foreign key?

```
CREATE TABLE junks (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE trunks (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
  -- no fk
);

-- and the below does not work!

--ALTER TABLE trunks ADD junk serial REFERENCES junks(id) NOT VALID;
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the `NOT VALID` option you found yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first add the column:

```
alter table trunks add column junk serial;
```

Then add the constraint to the table:

```
alter table trunks add constraint the_constraint_name
    FOREIGN KEY (junk)
    REFERENCES junks (id)
    not valid;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
ALTER TABLE trunks ADD CONSTRAINT FK_junk_id 
  FOREIGN KEY (id) 
  REFERENCES junks(id) 
  NOT VALID
;
```

See, e.g.: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/ddl-alter.html#AEN2758